# How to make an array filter work with an async function side?

Tags: javascript, arrays, firebase, loops, asynchronous

I'm developing a small card game web app. I'm using a "Rooms" system to hold each game and its players. Each room has a list of players, and I need to filter this list to only get a list of players that have a value in the Firebase Realtime DB. In this case, I'm checking their user presence in `/status/{userId}`.

I thought I would be able to piece this together fairly simply, but the filtered `players` array, or `activePlayers`, is getting read before the filter finishes.

**To demonstrate with a forEach:**

```
function debugActivePlayers (players) {
  activePlayers = []
  players.forEach(player => {
   firebase.ref('/status/' + player)
     .once('value')
     .then(snapshot => {
       console.log(snapshot.val()) // 'offline' or 'online' accordingly
       if (snapshot.val() === 'online') activePlayers.push(player)
       return null // <-- IDE throws a fit otherwise lol
     })
  })
  console.log(activePlayers)
}
```

What I expected to happen was:

```
offline
online
online
[userId1, userId2, userId3]
```

But what really happened was:

```
[]
offline
online
online
```

How do I make sure the `players.forEach` (or `players.filter`) runs synchronously even with async/promise logic inside (the firebase query)?

Comment: Please don't add solutions to your question.

Answer (score 2):

Try using "async/await" like below. This will wait for all asynchronous calls to get completed and then move forward to last console.log

```
async function debugActivePlayers (players) {
  let activePlayers = []

  for (let player of players) {
    let snapshot = await firebase.ref('/status/' + player).once('value')
    console.log(snapshot.val()) // 'offline' or 'online' accordingly
    if (snapshot.val() === 'online') activePlayers.push(player)
    return null // <-- IDE throws a fit otherwise lol
  }

  console.log(activePlayers)
}
```

EXPLAINATION - "for..of" with "await makes the execution of remaining statement on hold until all promises are resolved.. To demonstrate that pls test below

```js
function getValue(p) { return Promise.resolve(p) } 

async function test (players = [1,2,3]) {

  for (let player of players) {
    console.log(await getValue(player))
  }

  console.log('done')
}

test()
```

Comment: not sure why this is any different than the code he's already using... the console.log is not async...

Comment: Yes it looks console.log is not async, but "for..of" with "await" makes remaining execution wait until every promise is resolved.

Comment: @PariBaker added explanation with example for this. Pls have a look.

Comment: I can't believe I missed something so simple. See my original post for my final code that I just posted (or am about to).

Comment: function debugActivePlayers(players) {
  let activePlayers = players.map(player => {
    return firebase
      .ref("/status/" + player)
      .once("value")
      .then(snapshot => {
        console.log(snapshot.val());
        if (snapshot.val() === "online") {
          return player;
        } else {
          return;
        }
      });
  });
}

Comment: Good to know @kumo your issue is resolved!! Also, you now have the power of "async/await" to use further..